# Is there any function that takes a value from one sheet, and depending on that value, change the 2nd sheet?

Tags: function, google-sheets

So i want to make a function in google sheets with the general idea:

`IF cell in Sheet 2; Row D; VALUE=TRUE Then in Sheet 3,4,5...; the respective cell in row F` changes the background and text colour

**For Example**

`Row D, Cell 5 = True` ***in Sheet 2***; `Row F Cell 5` ***in Sheet 3*** `changes to red`

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are looking for by using the *INDIRECT* formula in *conditional formatting*.

1. In Sheet 3, select cell F5
2. Open conditional formatting
3. Ensure F5 is below *Apply to Range*
4. Ensure *Custom formula is* is below *Format cells if...*
5. Enter this formula into the formula bar, which says "look for the value in D5 of Sheet 2. If the value = TRUE, then apply formatting."

> =indirect("Sheet2!D5")=TRUE
> 6. Changing the highlight color to red, and any other formatting available in the menu.

[image]